# Adding first page in PDF while keeping my OCR and custom properties?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm trying to add a first page into a PDF document using iText.

The problem is that all my custom properties and my OCR are being deleted because adding a new page using `PdfWriter` is actuality creating a new document and copying all pages inside.

And so I've tried merging 2 PDFs when the first page is one PDF and the second PDF is the original file. The use of `PdfSmartCopy` is easy but the result is the same.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide some code and explain how your custom properties and your OCR are associated with the PDF. As a first info, though, using `PdfWriter` for document manipulation generally is utterly wrong. Depending on the exact use case, either use `PdfStamper` or some `Pdf*Copy*` class.

Comment: OCR done with ABBYY. No idea about its preferences.

Comment: PdfStamper had done done the job with method insertPage.
Thank you!